# Fading in/out a jquery list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to write a jquery function that loops through an unordered list (the ul element having the id "intro") and individually fades in and fades out each element.  This doesn't work, but I get no errors in the developer tools.  I also tried changing `var list = $("#intro");` to `var list = $("#intro li");` but no dice with that either

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
        function startAnimations(){

            var list = $("#intro");
            list.hide();
            list.each(function(li) {
                $(li).fadeIn(3000, function(){
                    $(li).fadeOut(3000);
                });

            });
        }
    </script>
```

Since the html was asked for:

```
<body onload="startAnimations()">
    <div class = "container">
        <div id = "inner">  </div>
        <div id = "right-col">
            <ul id = "intro">
                <li id = "greeting"> <h2 > sometext </h2> </li>
                <li id = "sidenote"> <h6 >  sometext </h6> </li>
                <li id = "sentence"> <h3 >  sometext </h3> </li>
                <li id = "sentence"> <h3 >  sometext</h3> </li>
                <li id = "sentence"> <h3 >  sometext</h3> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: can you share the html as well

Comment: you are grabbing an element with an id and you are trying to iterate it...?!?!

Comment: `list.each` doesn't make sense since IDs must be unique.

Comment: why not try `var list = $("ul li")` instead of using the id?

Comment: You have a problem in the each loop, the first param in the each callback is not the element it is  the index so you need to use `list.each(function (i, li) {`

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3DJkg/1/

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3DJkg/4/

Comment: you approach is not right, you are grabbing elements with id while id must be unique on page.

Comment: HI GUYS thanks for your replies.   Arun P Johny your solution made the fadein work, but I need each element to fadein/fadeout BEFORE the next.

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3DJkg/6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
function startAnimations() {
    $("#intro li").hide();

    function loop() {
        var $li = $("#intro li:first-child").fadeIn(3000, function () {
            $li.fadeOut(3000, function () {
                $li.appendTo('#intro');;
                loop()
            })
        });
    }
    loop()
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3DJkg/)

Comment: @JasonMarmon since you want to display only 1 item at a time, we display the first child, then fadeout it after a while... once the item is hidden we move to to the last child of the `ul` by calling `appendTo` because now we have to display the second item, if we move the current item to the last position, then the second item become the first child now so that we can repeat the loop

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
function fadeLi(elem) {
    elem.delay().fadeIn().delay(1500).fadeOut(500, function () {
        if (elem.next().length > 0) {
            fadeLi(elem.next());
        } else {
            fadeLi(elem.siblings(':first'));
        }
    });
}

$(function () {
    $('#intro li').hide();
    fadeLi($('ul li:first'));
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aauds/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
function startAnimations(){

             $("#intro").hide();

            $("#intro li").each(function() {
                 var _this = $(this);

                _this.fadeIn(3000, function(){
                    _this.fadeOut(3000);

                });

            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not selecting the li like you want. Try like this:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
        function startAnimations(){

            var list = $("#intro li");
            list.hide();
            list.each(function(index) {
                $(this).fadeIn(3000, function(){
                    $(this).fadeOut(3000);
                });

            });
        }
    </script>
```

The first parameter of this "each" function is not the element itself. It is the index

Answer (score 0):

Most of these look like good solutions. I may be reading into your question, but I'm assuming the advantage of fading each in & out individually is so you can stagger the transitions.

If that's the case, I'd recommend using jQuery's .delay() method:

https://api.jquery.com/delay/

I've forked the jsfiddle @arun made to show you how it could be done:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lgwm8/1/

```
function startAnimations() {
  var list = $("#intro li");
  list.hide();
  list.each(function (i, li) {
    $(li).delay(i * 500).fadeIn(3000, function () {
      $(li).fadeOut(3000);
    });
  });
}
startAnimations();
```